# Make a cannonball fly through the air using parabolas and XNA

Tags: c#, math, xna, position

I wanted to play around with XNA for a while so I wanted to try and make a game where a player can shoot a cannonball from a cannon and have it hit things. I wanted to make it look more realistic by having it arch through the air using parabolas but so for I haven’t been able to implement the equations I found online correctly. I was wondering if anyone knew the equation I could use to control the X and Y position of the cannon to generate a parabola. All I have is the degree of which I would like it to start, the cannon's start position and the velocity of which it is flying doesn’t really matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume a coordinate system with `y` positive being in the up direction, `x` increasing to the right.  Let's assume the cannon ball is shot from the origin (0, 0) up and to the right at a velocity of `v_init m/s` at an angle of `A` (be careful of radians vs. degrees; if your system requires angles to be in radians, you can convert degrees to radians by dividing degrees by 180 and multiplying by `pi`).

If the cannon ball is shot at an initial velocity of `v_init`, then the velocity in the `x` direction will be:

```
v_x = cos(A) * v_init
```

and the velocity in the `y` direction will be:

```
v_y = sin(A) * v_init
```

The height of the cannon ball will specified by:

```
h = (1/2)gt^2 + (v_y * t)
```

where g is the acceleration due to gravity of -9.81 m/s^2, and `t` is time in seconds.

So, at any given time `t`, your cannon ball will be at:

```
x_t = v_x * t
y_t = 1/2(-9.81)t^2 + (v_y * t)
```

You can use that equation to find out how long the ball will be in the air by setting the height to `0` and solving for `t`:

```
t_total = 2 * (v_y / 9.81)
```

The ball will reach maximum height half way through its flight, so the peak of your parabola will be at:

```
x_peak = 1/2 * t_total * v_x
y_peak = 1/2 * (-9.81) (t_total / 2)^2 + (v_y * t_total / 2)
```

And the cannon ball will land at:

```
x_land = t_total * v_x
y_land = 0
```

Comment: I think `h = (1/2)gt^2 + v_y` should be `h = (1/2)gt^2 + v_y*t + h0` where `h0` is the initial height; similarly for `y_t`.  `x_t` should also take into account the initial x position.

Comment: Yes.  I did say that we assume the cannon ball is shot from the origin at (0, 0).

Comment: But you also need to multiply the initial velocity (`v_x` and `v_y`) by the time `t`.  Your equations for the height / y component don't do that.  You only do that in the x direction.

Comment: thank you, working on fixing that right now